# MacBook Pro kernel panic report

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, memory, error, kernel-panic

My MacBook just restarted automatically. After the restart I got this error report:

```
    Anonymous UUID:       19FD699B-743D-2134-13B8-F9C25C3897D7

Sun Mar  6 13:26:32 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8007e16df2): Kernel trap at 0xffffff8007dce6b6, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0xffffffbf7fffffe8, CR3: 0x000000042ef70097, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0
RAX: 0xffffff7f80000000, RBX: 0xffffff802553e880, RCX: 0xffffff7f80000028, RDX: 0x0000003fffffffc0
RSP: 0xffffff81f06a3ce0, RBP: 0xffffff81f06a3d10, RSI: 0x00000000563af16d, RDI: 0xffffff800c2b95b0
R8:  0xffffff803be57580, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x00000000000002a0, R11: 0x000000014466cff4
R12: 0xffffff800c2b95b0, R13: 0xffffff800b25b000, R14: 0x0000000000112000, R15: 0xffffff803c52bc30
RFL: 0x0000000000010206, RIP: 0xffffff8007dce6b6, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0xffffffbf7fffffe8, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81f06a3990 : 0xffffff8007d2ad21 
0xffffff81f06a3a10 : 0xffffff8007e16df2 
0xffffff81f06a3bd0 : 0xffffff8007e33ca3 
0xffffff81f06a3bf0 : 0xffffff8007dce6b6 
0xffffff81f06a3d10 : 0xffffff8007d984f9 
0xffffff81f06a3f20 : 0xffffff8007e17354 
0xffffff81f06a3fb0 : 0xffffff8007e33bb5 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: firefox
Boot args: kext-dev-mode=1

Mac OS version:
14F27

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Wed Jul 29 02:26:53 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.40.9~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 58F06365-45C7-3CA7-B80D-173AFD1A03C4
Kernel slide:     0x0000000007a00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8007c00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8007b00000
System model name: MacBookPro9,2 (Mac-6F01561E16C75D06)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 6533833536095
last loaded kext at 14609786916: com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard 176.2 (addr 0xffffff7f8a1fe000, size 16384)
last unloaded kext at 99132904512: com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331    800.20.24 (addr 0xffffff7f89876000, size 2043904)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  5.0.14
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  5.0.14
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 5.0.14
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 5.0.14
at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch   4356
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   85.3
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.6f3
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.19.6
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.18.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   272.18.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.7.4
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.12
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.0.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.6f3
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 36
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.5
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.1
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   930.37.3
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   710.4.11
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  176.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   176.2
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.3.6f3
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  264.6
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.18.1
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.16
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.10.25
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97.4
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.6f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.6f3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.9.1d7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.30.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.2
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   730.60
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.8
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 720.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 398
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Model: MacBookPro9,2, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B0C, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.9 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.2f44
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393955353432382D3037392E4130304C4620
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393955353432382D3037392E4130304C4620
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.166.24.3)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.6f3 16238, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Samsung SSD 840 EVO 250GB, 250,06 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-8A8
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

Is maybe something wrong with my RAM? I upgraded the RAM with 2x8 GB Kingston RAM with 1600 MHz, its a MacBook Pro late 2012 with i7.

Comment: Did this crash > restart happen soon after the upgrade? I suggest you open up the MBP and reseat the RAM at the very least, if you suspect this is the only problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you suspect hardware issues, you should run [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257). Make sure to run it multiple times because sometimes issues happen when the computer is hot.

Generally you should only start worrying if your Mac restarts often with panics.